# How can I programatically detect overlap of SVG elements?

Tags: svg

I want to programatically create time lines similar to this:

[image: world war 2 timeline]

[source](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_zvVXcx2ULjw/TUknhRPeRiI/AAAAAAAAAZI/Z6K8eA2WWb4/s1600/ww2+timeline.jpg)

Each event will be at a vertical position determined by its datetime, but it can have arbitrary-length text, and must be positioned vertically so that it doesn't overlap with another event box.

**How can I programatically detect overlap of SVG elements so that I can move them up or down as needed?** A solution in any programming language or using any library is fine, but ideally I'd like to build this time line without involving a browser; I want this to be a command-line utility.

(I think this is possible because [GraphViz Dot](https://graphviz.org/about/) can output undirected graphs as SVG and keeps the nodes from overlapping - see the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_%28graph_description_language%29).)

Comment: Call getBBox() on each element. If the bounding boxes overlap you need to move one of them.

Comment: I'm sure you could do something with Batik. It suports SVG DOM and can be run from the command line.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/SVG::Timeline (Perl) might work